# PC getting stuck at the Intel boot screen with POST code 50

Tags: boot

One day my computer simply froze, I held down "power" and manually shut it down. Since then, whenever I turned it on, it gets stuck at the boot screen, and won't move past that.

Image of the boot screen:
[image: boot screen]

Close up:
[image: boot screen close up]

What I've tried:

- Hitting F12 or other keys to try to get into bios. Nothing happens.
- Unplug all USB peripherals, then turn it on, the same screen comes up.
- Unplug the hard drive, then turn it on, the same screen comes up.
- Unplug the memory stick, then turn it on, the computer beeps and screen is black.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What model computer exactly is this? If it's a custom built system, what exact model motherboard is it built around?

Comment: It's a custom built system. Looking at the board it looks like "Intel Desktop Board" model D33025.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the same or modern-day equivalent of a "Port 0x80" POST code.

[This](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-025434.htm) says the following, FWIW:

`50 – 5F    I/O Busses: PCI, USB, ISA, ATA, etc.`

and specifically for `50`:

`50     Enumerating PCI busses`

Try removing any Wifi or other PCIe hardware in this system, and see if it makes it go away.  Otherwise, you are probably looking at replacing the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post that might help with this if you haven't already encountered it. It appears that you'll need bios access to change settings but this person seemed to have fixed the very same issue. Try all of the FXX keys...just a shot.

Hope this helps!